Relatively recent sci-fi fantasy novel where the spaceship is alive and the magician/commander contains seven different versions of himself
The ship and commander are searching for specific new members to fill out the crew. They are seeking different crew members, such as engineer, captain, etc. The ship says it will be much stronger when all positions are filled.
I read what I believe was one of a series maybe in 2022(?). Commander was a nature magician and had memories of 7 different lives he had led.

In roughly which year did you read this? And can you tell us anything more about the plot or characters?

Are the new members intended to be/become versions of the magician? Replace him entirely? Serve as new blood?

I've not read this, but the mention of a wizard with memories of seven lives captaining a ship, in a fairly recent novel did remind me of the blurb for The Captain, first book in the Last Horizon series by Will Wight.

"To survive in this galaxy, you need a wand in one hand and a gun in
the other.”
On a little-known planet, Archmage Varic Vallenar casts a grand spell
to empower himself with the magical abilities of his alternate selves.
The ritual works too well, granting Varic not only the magic but also
the memories from six lives.
Including their gruesome deaths.
Now, Varic has power greater than any wizard in galactic history, but
he knows that won’t be enough. The enemies he faced in those alternate
lives were apocalyptic in scale. Terrors of technology and magic.
Nothing that he, or anyone, can defeat.
Sun-eating extra-dimensional insects, shadowy secret organizations,
genetically enhanced alien super-soldiers, ruthless megacorporations,
and hordes of cyborg undead all lurk in the darkest corners of the
galaxy, and Varic knows that any of them can become a world-ending
threat at any moment.
All these are beyond any wizard, no matter how many spells he’s
mastered or how many interstellar warships he’s rallied to his cause.
Hopeless, Varic finds himself trying to preserve what little he can
from the coming doom.
Until he hears rumors of a mythical starship, an invincible vessel of
heroes made to do battle against galactic threats. ​
A ship called The Last Horizon.

I also found a review that refers to recruiting crew members and the ship gaining capabilities as a result:

[...] getting dossiers of potential crewmates and recruiting them; needing
to complete a task for every crewmate; each crewmate unlocking an
upgrade to the ship [...]


Just to confirm, as someone who has read it, this is almost definitely correct.  I knew the answer just from the question title.

Sounds like the Black Ocean series by J.S. Morin, starting with Salvage Trouble

In the year 2254 gravity was officially declared to be magic; the
scientists gave up trying to figure it out and handed it over to the
wizards. Without the inherent respect for the laws of physics, the
wizards poked and prodded at gravity, poring over all that science
knew about the attraction of one object to the next, and dismissing it
as poppycock. They discovered ways around the tired old limits, and
gave birth to the first true starships. Some enlightened journalist,
covering the maiden voyage of the Impossible, noted that the ship was
shaped like a hand giving the middle finger to science.
The dreams of children came alive, and humanity expanded into the
cosmos, unlocking the secrets of the galaxy.
Who could have foreseen that three hundred years later, a
down-on-his-luck captain would be answering distress calls, hoping to
arrive in time to get first pick of the salvage ...

Brilliant series even if it’s not the exact one you are after, as it delivers on several of the ideas presented in your question.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I'm not seeing how this matches OP's description.

"The Quantum Magician" by Derek Künsken

Belisarius is a quantum man, an engineered Homo quantus who fled the
powerful insight of dangerously addictive quantum senses. He found a
precarious balance as a con man, but when a client offers him untold
wealth to move a squadron of warships across an enemy wormhole, he
must embrace his birthright to even try. In fact, the job is so big
that he'll need a crew built from all the new sub-branches of
humanity. If he succeeds, he might trigger an interstellar war, but
success might also point the way to the next step of Homo quantus
evolution.


Hi. Could you edit this answer to explain how The Quantum Magician matches the description of the novel asked about in the question? It'd help other users decide how likely it is to be the correct answer.

@LogicDictates - I'd be astounded if this is the correct answer. I'm not seeing anything that matches the question.
